# Display Image from Server in Java

Tags: java, jframe

I am new in Java programming.  My query is that I am having an image which is present on a server and I want to display that image inside the `JFrame`.  I tried using the `Image` class but that seems to be not working.

Please Note: I don't want to use applets for this, so is there some other method by which this can be done?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: how does the server make that image available (http, file share, other)? what do you have so far? what was your code with Image that didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it's a public accessible webserver, you can use [`URL#openStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) to get an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) out of an [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/image.png").openStream();
```

Then you can just create the [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with help of [`ImageIO#read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) the usual way.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
// ...
```